# How to perform C-Heap analysis

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection

Im trying to analyze my application which has thrown an Out of memory exception as below.

java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread

On googling a bit I was able to find that this might be because c heap has exhausted. I ve checked the GC logs and the heap memory is available and thats not the culprit. I need to analyse the c heap memory usage. Is there any tool which provides this kind of analysis.

When the heap( young gen / old gen) is full a garbage collection frees the memory, but what if the c heap is full. How does JVM/ is free memory here.?

Edit:
 I have checked with the thread count which is much less than what my application is able to handle. So thread does not seem to be the cause here. The exception occurs not when the thread count increases but when the application has been up for a very long time with moderate load and miderate thread count.

Comment: http://valgrind.org/ ?

Comment: This question feels like it is suffering from an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/176058). OOME: Unable to create new native threads typically happens because you have to many active threads running at a time. Why do you have so many threads, and how can you reduce that number. That is probably your 'X', that you should ask about instead of your proposed 'Y' (C-Heap analysis).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have checked with the thread count which is much less than what my application is able to handle. So thread does not seem to be the cause here. The exception occurs not when the three count increases but when the  application has been up for a very long time with moderate load and miderate thread count.

Comment: @Chinta Thanks for clarifying. It is probably a good idea to add that information to the question so you don't get answers (thinking it is thread count related) like my comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the JNI (or calling a program that does), you may have a memory leak in your native code. In particular, C and C++ are not garbage collected, so this is easy to accidentally cause.